# array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in php

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => tttt
    [1] => tttt
)
```

```
$terms_keys = array("terms");
$terms_array = array();
foreach ( array_map(null,$inv_terms) as $key => $value ) {
    $terms_array[] = array_combine($terms_keys, $value);
}
```

what is mistake done in my code ?

Comment: Is the array you show the `$inv_terms` array? PLease dont make us have to ask the obvious, take a second to make sure that question makes good sence to someone else

Comment: I think that `array_map()` is a bit of overkill. What do you think its doing

Comment: But the obvious answer is that `$value` is not an array, its `tttt` on both cases in that example

Comment: Maybe you should show us what you wanted the result of this code to be

Comment: @RiggsFolly  i am showing my array in $inv_terms=Array
(
    [0] => tttt
    [1] => tttt
) help to come out from this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $value param in the foreach is of course not an array its a scalar `tttt`, so you could make it into an array by doing `[$value]` in the combine

```
$terms_keys = array("terms");
$terms_array = array();
foreach ( array_map(null,$inv_terms) as $key => $value ) {
    $terms_array[] = array_combine($terms_keys, [$value]);
}
```

Or simplified as the `array_map()` does not achieve anything

```
$terms_keys = array("terms");
$terms_array = array();
foreach ( $inv_terms as $key => $value ) {
    $terms_array[] = array_combine($terms_keys, [$value]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how it could be advantageous to bloat your array structure with more depth, but generating the indexed array of associative arrays can be done without iterated function calls.  Just push the values into their new deep location using square-brace pushing syntax in a body-less foreach loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WhGbr))

```
$inv_terms = ['tttt', 'tttt'];
$result = [];
foreach ($inv_terms as $result[]['terms']);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'terms' => 'tttt',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'terms' => 'tttt',
  ),
)
```